# RoR: Counting records from day while querying datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I'm trying to create a loop for the last 15 days to give me counts of records on each day.

So @records should be an array of counts for the last 15 days.

However, the record stores dates as datetime (as you know), and I'm trying to reference any time within a single day.

```
@records = []

      15.times do |i|
        bar =  Records.all.count( 
          :type => 'large',
          :created_at => ((i-1).days.ago..i.days.ago)
          )
        @records << bar
      end
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
Record.where("date(created_at) > ?", 15.days.ago).group("date(created_at)").count
```

should give records count by days.

**Sample Output:**

```
 {"2011-07-02"=>4,
 "2011-07-04"=>5,
 "2011-07-05"=>16,
 "2011-07-06"=>12,
 "2011-07-11"=>19}
```

Comment: Care to write some documentation for Arel? Maybe a bunch of Arel one-liners?

Comment: actually I stole it right off the official Arel documentation :D http://goo.gl/ca9nJ

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this won't include NULLs, which I need. How would you .group() with iterations?

Comment: I think you should also get nil as one of the keys for null values. and what do you mean iterations?

Comment: Well I'd like the output to be an array of 15 counts, one for each of the last 15 days. So where in your solution should I add a condition to restrict the "created_at" attribute to the last 15 days?

Comment: Ok got that and it seems to work. What about including nulls? It's not including them for me...? The sample output above doesn't have it either... (Thanks for you continued help!)

Comment: Well, the sample output doesn't have nulls.. that's why it's called 'sample output'. but, in your case, why would created_at field ever be null in the table?

Comment: @dexter let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2963/discussion-between-galen-and-dexter)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to do the count without instantiating a lot of `Record` objects (which uses memory/time)

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows('SELECT DATE(created_at) AS d, COUNT(*) AS c FROM my_records_table GROUP BY DATE(created_at)')
```

This will give you an array of arrays:

```
> pp ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows('SELECT DATE(created_at) AS d, COUNT(*) AS c FROM my_records_table GROUP BY DATE(created_at)')
[["2011-06-23", "326"],
 ["2011-06-24", "337"],
 ["2011-06-25", "334"],
 ["2011-06-26", "353"],
 ["2011-06-27", "210"],
 ["2011-06-28", "330"],
 ["2011-06-29", "331"],
 ["2011-06-30", "338"],
 ["2011-07-01", "335"],
 ["2011-07-02", "366"],
 ["2011-07-03", "320"],
 ["2011-07-04", "338"],
 ["2011-07-05", "338"],
 ["2011-07-06", "299"],
 ["2011-07-07", "326"],
 ["2011-07-08", "314"],
 ["2011-07-09", "331"],
 ["2011-07-10", "335"],
```

...but I just saw dexter's answer and that is WAY better :)